# A linear-time algorithm for checking whether a spanning tree can use edges of weight at most some number?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm, prims-algorithm

[image]

The problem here is that i need to find the algorithm with linear time and all i can think of is Kruksal algorithm or Prim's algorithm which helps but that is already O(|E|log|E|).

Comment: Note: There's nothing here about a *minimal* spanning tree, just *any* spanning tree. Finding a spanning tree is a lot easier if you don't care about minimality.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint, think about what happens if you focus on the edges in the graph whose weights are less than or equal to b. What can you say about the MST in the graph if

- the graph given by those edges is connected?
- the graph given by those edges is not connected?

As a hint, think about what would happen if you were to run Kruskal's algorithm on the graph. You don't need to *actually* run Kruskal's algorithm - that's not fast enough - but do think about how it would run were you to run it.

Comment: Ok, followed your hint. is it true to say that if they are not connected, the sum of the MST will be the same of all the edges <= b, and if they are connected, the sum of the MST will be bigger then the sum of those edges ?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Can you prove it? :-)

Comment: Well intuitvly if they are connected they will close a circle faster thus an edge that will close the circle will be colored red and  thus not in  the MST ? i can of course write it more formally. So actually i should onlyate  use DFS here just to itirate over the edges ?

Comment: DFS sounds reasonable. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I could think of an algorithm like that:

```
1. go through each edge e in the graph (O(E)):
  if w(e) > b:
     remove e from the graph

2. if e with removed edges is disconnected (can be done in O(E)):
  return false

return true
```

this procedure should answer the question but I'm not 100% sure. Any comments and suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Checking if an edge forms a bridge takes time O(m + n), where m is the number of edges and n is the number of nodes. This overall procedure will take time O(mn + m^2), which isn't fast enough.

Comment: @templatetypedef hmm, you're right, but as I think of it now, this check not necessary